# Presto SQL filter by data type in where clause

Tags: sql, presto

I have a column, which should be VARCHAR; I need to cast these as doubles. Some values, however, are Booleans and trigger the error `Cannot cast false to DOUBLE`. How do I prevent this is the WHERE cause?

What's the easiest way to accomplish the below in presto?

```sql
...
WHERE Type(col) != BOOL
```

Or

```sql
...
WHERE type(col) = VARCHAR
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`try_cast`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#try_cast) and filter out `null`s:

```sql
-- sample data1
WITH dataset (column) AS (
    VALUES ('1'),
        ('not a double')
) 
--query
select * 
from (
        select try_cast(column as double) as column
        from dataset
    )
where column is not null
```

Output:

| column |
| --- |
| 1.0 |

Or use it in `where` (`where try_cast(...) is not null`)