# AWS Athena Query to convert complex string column to integer

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, casting, amazon-athena

I have an Athena table with a `string` column which looks like:

```
+-------------------+
| employee_size     |
+-------------------+
| GREATER THAN 2000 |
+-------------------+
| 500 - 999         |
+-------------------+
| 28.00             |
+-------------------+
| unknown           |
+-------------------+
| 563               |
+-------------------+
```

I want to convert the column values into `integer` if possible, else it should be `null`. So, the desired output should look like:

```
+---------------+
| employee_size |
+---------------+
|               |
+---------------+
|               |
+---------------+
| 28            |
+---------------+
|               |
+---------------+
| 563           |
+---------------+
```

I tried to use combination of queries the closest I think I could get was:

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN employee_size LIKE '% %' THEN NULL
        WHEN employee_size LIKE '%-%' THEN NULL
        WHEN regexp_like(employee_size,'([A-Za-z]') THEN NULL
        WHEN employee_size LIKE '%.%' THEN CAST(employee_size AS decimal)
        ELSE CAST(employee_size AS integer) 
    END AS employee_size 
FROM 
    "table_name";
```

But this code results in an error:

> INVALID_FUNCTION_ARGUMENT: end pattern with unmatched parenthesis

If you guys have faced something similar, please suggest a solution.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that if there is `decimal` value like `28.00` or `5.64` it should ignore whatever is there after the decimal and only have `28` or `5`

Comment: Would `12.34` be a valid integer?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have explicitly mentioned it in the question. If there is a `decimal` in the value then it should convert it to `integer` by ignore whatever comes after the `decimal`. Because in this case it does not make sense to have decimal employees

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presto SQL filter by data type in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71385256/presto-sql-filter-by-data-type-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like that?

```
with
 t as (
   select 'GREATER THAN 2000' employee_size
   union all
   select '500 - 999' employee_size
   union all
   select '28.00' employee_size
   union all
   select 'unknown' employee_size
   union all
   select '563' employee_size
   )
select cast(try_cast(employee_size as double) as integer) from t
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following logic:

```sql
SELECT
    CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(employee_size, '^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$')
         THEN REGEXP_EXTRACT(employee_size, '^[0-9]+') END AS employee_size
FROM yourTable;
```